# How do I find out who the author of a revision is in SVN? 

Tags: svn

How do I find out who the author of a revision is in SVN?

Comment: What tool are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
svn log -r <num> /path/to/working/copy
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `svn log -r 123123`: you'll get

```
r123123 | *user name* | date & time | length of log
Log message text
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it will be stored in the logs. How to check it depending on which SVN client/server you are using. e.g. using TortoiseSVN, you can just see it by click "Show log".....